# Is subject auxiliary inversion (do-support) unique to English?

Tags: english, questions, inversion

In English, some question sentences are formed by the inversion of the subject and the auxiliary verb.

I see you?

Do I see you?

*See I you?

From what I understand, the inversion cannot be done with non-copular non-auxiliary verbs unlike German.

Is this pattern of only inverting auxiliary and copular verbs unique to English?

Edit:

When I say "copular," I am referring only to the verb "to be".

He is Greg.

Is he Greg?

Comment: I don't know another example. This pattern introduced what is sometimes called "do-support", because if there is no other auxiliary, then "do" is introduced in order to invert; and some scholars thinks that "do" support was borrowed from Celtic languages; but it is not used in this pattern in any of them as far as I know.

Comment: AFAIK most of(?) the other Germanic languages allow inversion (German, Dutch, Swedish I know from personal experience): "Sehe ich dich?", "Zie ik jij?", "Ser jag dig?"

Comment: @OliverMason: If you read the question (rather than the title) it's not about inversion per se, but about inversion limited to auxiliaries.

Comment: @OliverMason inconsequential, but the Dutch is *zie ik jou?* with the accusative 2nd person pronoun.

Comment: All verbs invert the subject and auxiliary. That is what creates a question in English (intonation not included). I see you. Do I see you? You are rich. Are you rich? You play piano. Do you play piano?//What is a non-copular non-auxiliary verb? Active verbs (action) are not copular and they also undergo inversion in the interrogative.

Comment: @Lambie The vast majority of English verbs, essentially everything except auxiliaries, do not allow inversion: when the grammatical structure requires inversion, these verbs are forced to instead **insert** an empty prop-verb (_do_) to do it for them. That is the whole point here: simply inverting subject and verb, the way all other Germanic languages do it, is not the same as adding _do_ and then inverting; the question is asking if there are other languages that do it the English way rather than the normal Germanic way.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The question was: "Is this pattern of only inverting auxiliary and copular verbs unique to English?" The question is invalid.

Comment: @Lambie The term ‘copular’ is somewhat ambiguous cross-linguistically – sometimes it means only verbs meaning ‘to be’, other times it’s a broader category that includes verbs like ‘seem’, ‘become’, ‘get’, ‘feel’. Both definitions are equally valid. Taking the former as the intended definition here, the question here is also perfectly valid. English does indeed have a pattern of only inverting auxiliary verbs (including the copula _be_, which is usually considered an auxiliary); other verbs do not invert. Asking whether that pattern is unique to English is valid.

Comment: Not using of [do-support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support) with non-auxiliary verbs is just archaic. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English claims: 「No *do*-support in questions and negatives. Questions were usually formed by inverting subject and finite verb, and negatives by placing ne before the finite verb, regardless of which verb.」 https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/culicover.1/Publications/do.pdf claims: 「Ellegård shows that certain verbs, such as *know*, *say*, and *think*,
“resisted the usage of *do*-support, at least in negatives, until as late as the
nineteenth century”」

Comment: @Arfrever Yeah one counter example I saw of do-support was the phrase “have you any idea how important this is?” It’s a bit archaic but seems mostly grammatical.

Comment: ["What Say You?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_4-rCROcsM). It should have been "What say **ye**?" for better grammar :) . ("you" was oblique form of "ye": *I* - *me*, *thou* - *thee*, *he* - *him*, *we* - *us*, *ye* - *you*, *they* - *them*)

Comment: @Arfrever Inversion without _do_-support with _say_ is still somewhat acceptable in current English (e.g., the jury is still asked, “What say you?” in US courtrooms) – it’s formulaic and archaic rather than obsolete, so using it with modern pronouns is fine. Unless I’m misremembering, Tolkien generally doesn’t use _thou_ and _ye_ in writings, so “What say you?” would be the expected thing for Aragorn to say. The Wikipedia article you link to is for Old English, which is beyond obsolete; it’s a whole different language. (Compare also ‘they know not what they do’ for an example with _know_.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I consider inversion and negation without *do*-support with all non-auxiliary verbs, not just *say*, to be archaic, instead of obsolete. By the way, [pronoun *ye*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ye_(pronoun)) is supposedly still used in parts of Canada and Ireland.

Comment: "these verbs are forced to instead insert an empty prop-verb (do) to do it for them." That is not accurate. In English, *do* is not "an empty prop verb".** Do you speak French** Answer: Yes, I **do**: No, I **don't.** "I **do speak French, don't you**? Nothing is being added. That auxiliary is part of the structure of the verb form for active verbs in the interrogative and negative verb **forms** in the simple present.

Comment: Now, the question has been edited and it says non-copular refers to the verb *be*. Okay, right.  But I still ask, what is: ("From what I understand, the inversion cannot be done with non-copular non-auxiliary verbs").

Comment: @Lambie _Do_ is indeed a semantically empty prop-verb in both your examples; it is there for syntactic reasons only. The question in the first example inserts _do_ because ‘*speak you’ is not possible (outside formulaic, archaising use); in the statement in the second example, _do_ is inserted to signal emphasis rather than because of inversion, but it is still inserted. The answer in the first and the tag question in the second example likewise insert _do_, but then also elide the main verb _speak [French]_, making _do_ a kind of pro-verb.

Comment: And a non-copular, non-auxiliary verb is just any verb that is neither the copula _be_ nor an auxiliary verb. Since inversion only takes place with auxiliary verbs (including the copula), it’s all those verbs where inversion _doesn’t_ take place.

Comment: @QuinaliSolaji: For many British English speakers, (particularly older ones like myself) lexical _have_ can invert as well as auxiliary _have_,  though interestingly it often takes a semantically empty _got_, which makes it syntactically an auxiliary. _Have you any eggs?_ comes across as more formal than _Have you got any eggs?_. When I was young, we didn't say _Do you have any eggs?_ - that was an Americanism we heard on TV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SAI is not the same as do-support, which your question is really about (if I read it correctly). Other than English, do-support is also attested in Monnese and perhaps a few other languages, but it doesn't seem very common (e.g. Russian, which arguably is like English in not raising main verbs, doesn't have it AFAIK; in polar questions the main verb raises all the way).

German/Dutch has something like do-support when the VP is fronted and the main verb is therefore not available to raise.

Er liest gerne Bücher
he reads gladly books
'He likes to read books.'

Liest er gerne Bücher?
reads he gladly books
'Does he like to read books?'

[Bücher lesen] *(tut) er gerne
books read.INF does he gladly
'He likes to read books.'

Comment: The Scandinavian languages also have this; they additionally also use _do_ for tag questions like English, though not for inversion purposes (interrogatives, preposed AdvP, conditional clauses) or emphasis.

Comment: I see; I assumed that SAI was only for auxiliaries and not main verbs.

Comment: @QuinaliSolaji I meant to say by that that “do” is not the only auxiliary verb. But reading your question again, I realize I probably misread it as being specifically about do-support.